# Getting Multiple DataFrames (Segment) using a Binary Mask

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how if it is possible (and if it is how) to get multiple dataframes from a binary mask using pandas.

Imagine that I have the following dataframe:

```
   A  B Mask
0  0  1  0
1  2  3  1
2  4  5  1
3  6  7  0
4  8  9  1
5  5  6  1
```

I want to obtain one dafaframe df1:

```
   A  B Mask
1  2  3  1
2  4  5  1
```

and another df2

```
   A  B Mask
1  8  9  1
2  5  6  1
```

Is this possible without recurring to filter?

Comment: Why do you split the rows after two matches?

Comment: Because in the third position of the mask there is a 0, so it "means" that from that position on, I will need to create a new DataFrame. In fact, what I am trying to do is segmentation of a DataFrame based on a binary mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
[g[g.Mask != 0] for k, g in df.groupby((df.Mask == 0).cumsum()) if len(g) > 1]

#[   A  B  Mask
# 1  2  3     1
# 2  4  5     1,
#    A  B  Mask
# 4  8  9     1
# 5  5  6     1]
```

Comment: Thanks :) I tried with loops, but the solution I came up with was ugly. I knew that there should be a solution that was simple and elegant. Thanks!